# Can an application have both java 7 and java 8 class files and deployed on java 8 JVM

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, java-7

I have an emergency kind of situation. I have one application which is compiled using java 7 and same is running on Java 8 jvm. Now i need to modify certain files. However, i have only java 8 sdk. Can i deploy java 8 compiled class files? Will java 7 byte code be able to call java 8 files?

Comment: code written with jdk8 will run for sure on a jvm8

Comment: Are you recompiling and redeploying everything, including the classes previously compiled with JDK 7?  Just test it properly before deploying to production.

Comment: "I don't have the luxury to do experiment." CTRL+C -> New Folder -> CTRL+V -> Deploy project to different/new instance. Now you have the luxury to experiment. Get a test environment, if I was your customer and I got to know that basically everything you do is an "open-heart" operation because there is no dedicated testing environment, I wouldn't be your customer for much longer.

Comment: @RiaanNel  No. I am only deploying single class file.

Comment: @Wep0n i understand your emotions. May be i should delete that line from the question. It is difficult for me to give explanation why i wrote it. Only reason to write such thing was to avoid those answers which would have suggested me to " Try it yourself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM 8 will run class files from all previous compilers.  There is no problem for class file to call another compiled on a different compiler.  This is evident when you use 3rd party libraries and you don't care which compiler was used to build the jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, bytecode compiled for Java 7 can use classes compiled for Java 8, assuming both run on a Java 8 or newer JRE. This is exactly what happens when your application compiled for Java 7 runs in a Java 8 environment, as your classes are using the JRE classes.

But these classes compiled for Java 8 won’t run on Java 7 JREs. If that’s intended, you can still use the `-target 1.7` option to let the `javac` command of the Java 8 JDK produce class files for the Java 7 environment. However, there are catches. `javac` requires you to also use the `-source 1.7` option to enable the Java 7 target, so you can’t use new language features in this case, also, you have to discipline yourself not to use newer API features which are not present in Java 7.

There is the `-bootclasspath` option allowing to redirect to a different set of JRE classes to avoid such mistakes, but since you don’t want to download such an environment, this doesn’t help. This will be solved with the Java 9 JDK. With that JDK, you can simply specify the `--release 7` option, which combines `-source 1.7`, `-target 1.7` and `-bootclasspath`, whereas the JDK provides an appropriate API description itself.